# System.OutOfMemoryException in HtmlDocument of HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#

```
using (Stream reader = propertyBag.GetResponse())
{
    reader.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    htmlDoc.Load(reader, true);
}
```

but htmlDoc.Load(reader, true); throw this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll

We have program that runs 24h/day and check some html data. It works for few hours then we get this error. Error is always related to HtmlDocument of HtmlAgilityPack.

How to prevent this?

Comment: How big is the html document?  Are you disposing of the HtmlDocument object?

Comment: when this happens, is the memory genuinely growing to unrealistic amounts, or...? (OOM doesn't always relate to memory load)

Comment: It's just a guess, but I think you might be running out of memory.

Comment: i have 4 gb of ram in this computer where i am testing. @Foole no i don't think so. Where to use dispose()?

Comment: i search but i can not dispose HtmlDocument. Dispose is not supported in HtmlDocument ...

Comment: Switching to x64 helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a memory profiler to check what objects are not disposed. Maybe Agility Pack has a memory leak or your code using it has.

One of the best profilers I've used is **[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)**, which allows you to take two snapshots at different points in time, compare them and display objects which are not disposed.

Comment: It may not be the `HtmlDocument` instance that are hanging in the memory. And it's not the case of calling Dispose() method but loosing references to some objects so they can be reclaimed by GC.